# How to ensure ViewModel#onCleared is called in an Android unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

This is my MWE test class, which depends on AndroidX, JUnit 4 and MockK 1.9:

```
class ViewModelOnClearedTest {
    @Test
    fun `MyViewModel#onCleared calls Object#function`() = mockkObject(Object) {
        MyViewModel::class.members
            .single { it.name == "onCleared" }
            .apply { isAccessible = true }
            .call(MyViewModel())

        verify { Object.function() }
    }
}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    override fun onCleared() = Object.function()
}

object Object {
    fun function() {}
}
```

Note: the method is protected in superclass `ViewModel`.

I want to verify that `MyViewModel#onCleared` calls `Object#function`. The above code accomplished this through reflection. My question is: can I somehow run or mock the Android system so that the `onCleared` method is called, so that I don't need reflection?

From the `onCleared` JavaDoc:

> This method will be called when this ViewModel is no longer used and will be destroyed.

So, in other words, how do I create this situation so that I know `onCleared` is called and I can verify its behaviour?

Comment: You could `public override fun onCleared()`, but that exposes the method which is not good, as the method should only be called by the Android system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

In this answer, Robolectric is used to have the Android framework invoke `onCleared` on your `ViewModel`. This way of testing is slower than using reflection (like in the question) and depends on both Robolectric and the Android framework. That trade-off is up to you.

---

#### Looking at Android's source...

...you can see that `ViewModel#onCleared` is only called in `ViewModelStore` (for your own `ViewModels`). This is a storage class for view models and is owned by `ViewModelStoreOwner` classes, e.g. `FragmentActivity`. So, when does `ViewModelStore` invoke `onCleared` on your `ViewModel`?

It has to store your `ViewModel`, then the store has to be cleared (which you cannot do yourself).

Your view model is stored by the `ViewModelProvider` when you `get` your `ViewModel` using `ViewModelProviders.of(FragmentActivity activity).get(Class<T> modelClass)`, where `T` is your view model class. It stores it in the `ViewModelStore` of the `FragmentActivity`.

The store is clear for example when your fragment activity is destroyed. It's a bunch of chained calls that go all over the place, but basically it is:

1. Have a `FragmentActivity`.
2. Get its `ViewModelProvider` using `ViewModelProviders#of`.
3. Get your `ViewModel` using `ViewModelProvider#get`.
4. Destroy your activity.

Now, `onCleared` should be invoked on your view model. Let's test it using Robolectric 4, JUnit 4, MockK 1.9:

1. Add `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)` to your test class.
2. Create an activity controller using `Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity::class.java)`
3. Initialise the activity using `setup` on the controller, this allows it to be destroyed.
4. Get the activity with the controller's `get` method.
5. Get your view model with the steps described above.
6. Destroy the activity using `destroy` on the controller.
7. Verify the behaviour of `onCleared`.

#### Full example class...

...based on the question's example:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class ViewModelOnClearedTest {
    @Test
    fun `MyViewModel#onCleared calls Object#function`() = mockkObject(Object) {
        val controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity::class.java).setup()

        ViewModelProviders.of(controller.get()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

        controller.destroy()

        verify { Object.function() }
    }
}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    override fun onCleared() = Object.function()
}

object Object {
    fun function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 19):

In kotlin you can override the protected visibility using `public` and then call it from a test.

```kotlin
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    public override fun onCleared() {
        ///...
    }
}
```

Comment: A little ``@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.TESTS)`` on top of `onCleared()` and it's all good

Comment: with androidx.annotation: ```@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PROTECTED) public override fun onCleared() {...```

Comment: Note: this won't call .close() for tags and closables registered with the ViewModel. So you might be testing behavior that never happens in real life. (e.g. using a closable that would be closed passes in tests, but crashes in app)

Answer (score 13):

I've just created this extension to ViewModel:

```
/**
 * Will create new [ViewModelStore], add view model into it using [ViewModelProvider]
 * and then call [ViewModelStore.clear], that will cause [ViewModel.onCleared] to be called
 */
fun ViewModel.callOnCleared() {
    val viewModelStore = ViewModelStore()
    val viewModelProvider = ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore, object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = this@callOnCleared as T
    })
    viewModelProvider.get(this@callOnCleared::class.java)

    //Run 2
    viewModelStore.clear()//To call clear() in ViewModel
}
```

Comment: This depends on `ViewModelStore#clear` to call `ViewModel#onCleared`, and therefore that call is somewhat hidden among these lines of code. However, this solution is quite nice due to its brevity, no need for reflection nor Robolectric / Android tests, and the fact that on Android normally it's a `ViewModelStore` instance that performs the call. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Results in "CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`"

Comment: This is genius! Perfectly simulates what happens in real life, ensuring `Closeable`s are also `close()`d before calling `onCleared`, so it exhibits the same behavior as if it was running in the app.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, if you create your test class in the same package (within the test directory) as of the ViewModel class (here, MyViewModel), then you can call `onCleared` method from the test class; since protected methods are also package private.

Comment: Yes, it works like that for Java. But I'm not using Java.

Comment: Yes, I know, it for users who are looking for a solution in Java; since the title does not specifically mention 'in Kotlin'.

Comment: FYI, this also works in Kotlin. You can change the package within the file, for example, **package androidx.lifecycle**, and then that will let you access package-private stuff.

Comment: Tip: don't create the test class in the same package, that's confusing. Just create a `ViewModelAccessor` class with a static `clear(ViewModel)` method. It's a bit more reusable. And it's callable from Kotlin and Java easily.